# Going mad with date in SQL and c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am developing a C# application, and I have a `date` column in SQL Server.

I am performing a query based on date, using `DateTimePicker`. I have changed the format of datetime picker to short, now it displays date as `mm-dd-yyyy`

Now while executing I get correct output from date 1-12 but as soon as I select 13 date I get error as

> *conversion failed when converting date/time from character string*

I don't know what is happening!

Comment: Can you show us **how** you query with that date? What does your query look like? Are you using **parameters** as you should? Setting the parameter type to `SqlDbType.Date` usually solves most issues....

Comment: most safe option would be to format date into ISO format when passing to DB

Comment: it sounds to me like you're querying with strings rather than parsing the string at the UI, and doing the query with a date/datetime parameter.... how are you doing the query?

Comment: If "1-12" works but "1-13" doesn't I would strongly suspect that (for whatever reason) you have "**dd-mm**-" format.

Comment: my query is as follows:
`Select roll_number,name`
`from Attendance_table`
`where date=dateTimePicker1.Text`
how should i use SqlDbType.Date? please guide me, i dont know abt it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're using the formatted string from that `DateTimePicker` to build an SQL query on the fly via format strings or concatenation.

Don't do that.

Date/time string literals in SQL tend to use a sane format (i.e. ISO 8601) where the order of the parts differs. The fact that it blows up when you change a piece from 12 to 13 should give it away, actually.

An `SqlCommand` has parameters (you can insert in the query with `@foo`. Using those will ensure that everything gets passed in the right way and properly quoted:

```
using (SqlCommand c = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    c.CommandText = "Select roll_number,name from Attendance_table where date=@date";
    c.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
    using (var r = c.ExecuteReader()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

(roughly – you should consult the documentation for proper usage, it's been a while that I wrote such things)